# export mysql tables and zipArchive

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've searched all the posts, but still couldn't get it to work. With button press I want to export "page preset" to be precise it's restaurant menu preset, it includes css files, mysql tables etc. I want to be able to import it to another 'menu'. First I'm trying to export mysql database. Should I use `mysqldump` or `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE` ?
I'm using this line:
`exec("mysqldump --user=$dbusername --password=$dbpassword restaurantsdb meal --where=restaurant_id=$restId > tables/meal.sql");`

`restaurantsdb` is database name and `meal` = table name. I also want rows `WHERE 'restaurant_id' = {id}`

 I'm trying to understand how mysqldump works, should this line work for me?
Next I'm  creating zipArchive file, adding some directories, I tried adding .txt file, that one works, but it doesn't seem to find `meal.sql` file.

```
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ( $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    exit("error");
    }
    $zip->addEmptyDir('TestFiles');
    $zip->addEmptyDir('tables');


    $fileToZip = __DIR__.'/hello.txt';
    $zip->addFile($fileToZip, "TestFiles/text.txt");

    $fileToZip = __DIR__.'/tables/meal.sql';
    $zip->addFile($fileToZip, "tables/meal.sql");

    $download_file = file_get_contents( $file_url );
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file_url),$download_file);

    $zip->close();

        header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zip_file).'"');
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($zip_file);

    unlink($zip_file);

    exit;
```

Also, is it better to export as `.sql` or `.csv` ? Later when importing, I need to be able to change id's of all rows to specified, just before importing to database. It's basically cloning same data, but different id's.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do, specifically what CSS files you are talking about, but I can take some guesses. SQL is great for moving data exactly. If that works for you and you can run an UPDATE after import to change IDs, I'd probably go with that. CSV is easier to work with from a PHP perspective, for instance if you want to loop over things and change IDs before INSERT. CSV is also easier to audit with a tool like Excel. What you didn't mention was JSON which is also a great serialization format that _might_ work for you similarly to CSV.

Comment: If you just want to dump the data and you need to change some data before importing it again, then dumping it as a SQL file might make it harder. If it's just the contents, you could store it as csv, json (might be a bit easier) or any format you prefer.

Comment: I want to export mysql tables and add it to zip is this command correct for exporting? `exec("mysqldump --user=$dbusername --password=$dbpassword restaurantsdb meal --where=restaurant_id=$restId > tables/meal.csv");` where `restaurantsdb` is database name and `meal` is  table name.

Comment: Or should I use `SELECT * OUTFILE` for exporting tables in csv?